# Getting values from variables with function scope

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a homework project to use an API to display the weather. Originally, I declared variables "latty" and "lonny" at the top of my script, in the a main function scope everything else was inside, and later they were set = to latitude and longitude using navigator.geolocation. After setting them to the coordinates I then tried to use them as part of the URL line that is sent to the API, but the values for latty and lonny never carried over. I thought declaring them in the parent function would allow them to be used in subsequent, nested functions. Since geolocation requires a function in order to get coordinates, I ended up having to nest the entire script within the getPosition() function in order to be able to use the values that it retrieves:

```
this.addEventListener("load", navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition));

function getPosition(position) {
  var latty = position.coords.latitude;
  var lonny = position.coords.longitude;
  var url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
  var apiKey = '5a4ae697ea6b02e5a4ae697ea6b02e/';

weatherAjax();

function weatherAjax(){
$.ajax({
  url: url + apiKey + latty + "," + lonny + degreeType,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    $("#weatherID").html("<h1>" + Math.round(data.currently.temperature) + degreeSymbol + data.currently.summary + "</h1>");
  }
}); 
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, without nesting everything within getPosition()? It seems strange that I cannot get information from geolocation, set those coordinates to a variable, and call them into another function. I couldn't figure out how to return that information, either, and I won't share that mess with you here because it was terrible.

I understand the basic idea of scope as: you can only access variables that are "higher up" in the nesting order. Sibling-level or child functions will not "share" variable access. Is this correct? Can this be improved upon?

Comment: It sounds like you may be confusing function scope with synchronous and asynchronous code.  Since you have *working* code, this isn't entirely a duplicate.  But the answers you're looking for are probably here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: `getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous. So you can't access the data until it has been received. It's the same as trying to eat a pizza that hasn't been delivered yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your script.

First of all, `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)` returns `undefined`, so you're not actually attaching an event handler to the page `load` event, and that call to `addEventListener()` does nothing and fails silently.

Secondly, there is a better way of organizing the script so that you don't have to nest your script in the `getPosition()` callback. **Use function parameters**:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);

function getPosition(position) {
  var latty = position.coords.latitude;
  var lonny = position.coords.longitude;
  var url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
  var apiKey = '5a4ae697ea6b02e5a4ae697ea6b02e/';

  weatherAjax(latty, lonny, url, apiKey);
}

function weatherAjax(latty, lonny, url, apiKey) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url + apiKey + latty + "," + lonny + degreeType,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
      $("#weatherID").html("<h1>" + Math.round(data.currently.temperature) + degreeSymbol + data.currently.summary + "</h1>");
    }
  }); 
}
```

So, finally, if you want this to actually run after the page loads, throw all of that into an anonymous callback to `load`:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  // everything above goes in here
});
```

All together, you get this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);

  function getPosition(position) {
    var latty = position.coords.latitude;
    var lonny = position.coords.longitude;
    var url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
    var apiKey = '5a4ae697ea6b02e5a4ae697ea6b02e/';

    weatherAjax(latty, lonny, url, apiKey);
  }

  function weatherAjax(latty, lonny, url, apiKey) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url + apiKey + latty + "," + lonny + degreeType,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function (data) {
        $("#weatherID").html("<h1>" + Math.round(data.currently.temperature) + degreeSymbol + data.currently.summary + "</h1>");
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I had used setTimeout without realising it might actually take more than 2s delay at some point since it had never failed to do so. I changed my code according to your answer.